# Alignment issues of the text written after math mode inside tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I am trying to align the text, which is written after an equation inside `tcolorbox`. Please see the code snippet below-

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (fusion){
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title=Data Fusion, hbox]
            $
            c_i = \mathbf{T}_i * p_i            
            $
            where $c_i$ is center point at $i$
        \end{tcolorbox}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is how generated PDF looks like-

[image]

**I want to put the explanation of this equation in next line.**

*PS: This diagram contains many tikz nodes hence I am using `tcolorbox` inside `tikzpicture`. However, in this question, it is not relevant to show the entire code.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have line breaks in an `hbox` I believe. If you remove `hbox` you can (e.g. add a paragraph break after the math, or use display math), but then of course the width of the box becomes `\textwidth`, not the width of the text in the box. You can remove `hbox` and set the width manually, or use something like a `tabular` (or stack, like in Steven's answer) inside the box with `hbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (fusion){
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title=Data Fusion,hbox]
            \begin{tabular}{l}
            $ c_i = \mathbf{T}_i * p_i$ \\
            where $c_i$ is center point at $i$
            \end{tabular}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (fusion){
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title=Data Fusion, width=6cm]
            $
            c_i = \mathbf{T}_i * p_i            
            $

            where $c_i$ is center point at $i$
        \end{tcolorbox}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (fusion){
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title=Data Fusion]
            \[
            c_i = \mathbf{T}_i * p_i            
            \]

            where $c_i$ is center point at $i$
        \end{tcolorbox}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for describing all possible answers in one single post. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 6):

I am sure there is an easier way...but since you have specified an `\hbox` for the `tcolorbox`, multiline output must be achieved in an alternate fashion than normal line breaking.

Note: the alignment is controlled by the `l`eft parameter.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,stackengine}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (fusion){
        \begin{tcolorbox}[title=Data Fusion, hbox]
            \stackengine{5pt}{$
            c_i = \mathbf{T}_i * p_i            
            $}
            {where $c_i$ is center point at $i$}
            {U}{l}{F}{F}{S}
        \end{tcolorbox}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same result can be attained with slightly different syntax:

```
        \renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
        \stackunder[5pt]{$
        c_i = \mathbf{T}_i * p_i            
        $}
        {where $c_i$ is center point at $i$}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Surprisingly it is the first time I saw `stackengine` package. Thanks for it!